# Hash key is storing only the last element of loop

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am trying to store the array values in the hash, but the hash key is storing only the last value of array in the for loop.

My expected output is, 'STORE' key should have all the array elements.
I knew there are few other ways to store the array values in the hash, but I curious why the below script doesn't work.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array = (1,2,3);
my %record;

for my $array(@array) {
    $record{"STORE"} = $array;
}
print Dumper \%record;
```

Comment: If you know that `$record{"STORE"}` is a scalar value, and you are doing scalar assignment with `=`, then it is the same as for example `$foo = $array`, and you should not be surprised that will be overwritten with each loop iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hash has only the last value from the array because you keep overwriting the value in the `for` loop.

One way to store all values from the array is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array = (1,2,3);
my %record;

for my $array (@array) {
    push @{ $record{"STORE"} }, $array;
}

print Dumper \%record;
```

This stores the array as a reference.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'STORE' => [
                       1,
                       2,
                       3
                     ]
        };
```

Another way to store the whole array is to assign it to an array reference:

```
my @array = (1,2,3);
my %record;

$record{"STORE"} = [@array];

print Dumper \%record;
```

Refer to [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc)